# Enable SSL Certificate/HTTP to HTTPS Sharepoint Web App - Sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, ssl, https

I have a Sharepoint 2019 on-premise instance running a web app with the following URL:

> share.mangos.com

on port 80 without SSL enabled, I set up the SSL following the steps from this blog post:

> https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/20/a-guide-to-https-and-secure-sockets-layer-in-sharepoint-2013/

A difference is that I am running Windows Server 2022 Eval with IIS 10.0, and didn't find IIS Resource kit for IIS 10, so I didn't run SelfSSL.exe inside the resource kit, so created the Self-Signed Certificate using IIS Manager on the same server running Sharepoint.

When I check on the browser

> HTTP://share.mangos.com works fine but doesn't show or recognize the SSL Cert.

> HTTPS://share.mangos.com doesn't connect and show the error Secure connection failed and Firefox did not connect

So what I am missing, or did wrong, or it is outdated the steps or there is another method? for Sharepoint 2019?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP:// endpoint will not use certificate, so "doesnt's show SSL Cert" - is OK.

as for HTTPS:// endpoint:
if you're using the self-signed certificate on your website, then it must be aslo [installed to your OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate) as **Trusted Root CA Cert** on the computer from which you connect to the site (*Part 6* of the instruction you mentioned).

Also, Firefox can ignore OS certificates list and use its own list.
In that case you should add your self-signed cert to Firefox's inner certificate list (somewhere in *Tools > Options > Advanced* (or *Privacy and Security*) > *Certificates: View Certificates - Authorities - Import*)

Comment: oh, thanks for the reminder of that steps, the self-signed certificate is already installed on Trusted Root CA Cert as tried for Firefox importing but is still rejected.